# How to set vector values from 0 index?

Tags: c++

I have initialized the array with n elements in the constructor of Array class. Now, if I want to set the values of these elements, then by using 'set function', values are getting set after n+1 index. How do I set the values from 0 index of vector?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    class Array{
        vector<int> array;
    public:
        Array(int n):array(n){}

        int binarySearch(int n,int i,int f)
        {
            int mid= (i+f)/2;
            if(i!=f || array[mid]==n){     
                if(array[mid] == n)            
                    return mid;           
                else if(array[mid] < n)
                    return binarySearch(n,mid+1,f);
                else
                return binarySearch(n,i,mid-1);
            }
            else
               return NULL;
        }

        int set(int n){
            array.push_back(n);
        }

        int size(){
            return array.size();
        }

        void print(){
            int i=0;
            while(i<array.size()){
                cout<<array[i]<<endl;i++;
            }
        }
     };

int main()
{
    cout<<"ENter no. of element for the array to be initialized with"<<endl;
    int n,x;
    cin>>n;
    Array a(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>x;
        a.set(x);
    }
    cout<<"Enter the no. to be searched"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<a.binarySearch(x,0,a.size());
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `array.push_back(n);` simply adds `n` as an additional value to the end of the existing vector. You probably meant something else!

Comment: You want `array.assign(0)`. I cannot **possibly** believe that this method is *that hard* to find using Google.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back` pushes to the back of the array, i.e appends after the `n` elements that you create in the constructor. You can use `[]` operator to set the elements individually. Or if you are setting them all to the same, I think there is a constructor for that.

Answer (score 0):

no need to create the `a` Array with `n` objects..
simply get `n` numbers from the users and use the `set` method to push them into the vector